# Wordpress effect / animmation showing categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the image below, do you know:

```
1) What is the name of the effect that makes the category shows-up/pop-up/zoom in?
2) What plugin does have this feature?
```

[Please identify this effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VaON.gif)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called **Zoon In Down** animation. You can visit [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and select **zoomInDown** animation to see it.

Currently I see no plugin has this animation as your example. But you can implement Animate.css in your theme:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-animate', THEME_DIR_URI . '/includes/css/animate.css' );
```

For more information, you can visit [Animate.css on github](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css).